# ': not a valid identifierelease error message in bash

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I created a bash file and put a content like

```
echo "Enter current release dir:"
read release
php zipping.php
scp build.zip user@ipaddress:/path/to/releases/$release
scp docs.text user@ipaddress:/path/path/releases/$release
echo "success moving build.zip to live"
sudo rm build.zip
echo "deleted build.zip"
```

then run `bash release`

it successfully execute bash command, but

I moved that file somewhere and created a new bash file using `touch release`

and put content like

```
echo "Enter current release dir:"
read release
```

Now I got

```
Enter current release dir:
': not a valid identifierelease
```

error

Any idea?

Comment: What is the output of `type -a release`

Comment: Check your script for `\r`. You can do so using `cat -A` for instance, if you see `^M` in the output those are `\r`s and can remove them with `dos2unix` if available or `tr -d $'\r'` otherwise

Comment: In particular the error message you see looks something like `'somethingsomethingrelease\r': not a valid identifier`, where the part after the `\r` is written from the start of the line, overwriting previous content

Answer (score 0):

After digging i just found this [article](https://superuser.com/questions/1244671/not-a-valid-identifier-for-read)

and I realized the i am in windows environment using WSL and have Ubuntu 16.04 installed therefore the file is windows encoding.

The solution is `ssh user@ipaddress` and in there performed `touch release` and download that using `scp user@ipaddress:/user/release /path/to/download/release`